# What is inductive case?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

nines(1) =  9

nines(2) = 99

nines(3)= 999

nines(4)=  9999

⋮

Let P(n) ≡ [nines(n) + 1 = 10^n]. Prove that P(n) is true for all n ≥ 1, by mathematical induction. Use the induction schema [P(1) ∧ ∀k [P(k) → P(k + 1)]] → ∀n P(n).

- What is the inductive case, ∀k [P(k) → P(k + 1)]?

I am working on this problem and i am pretty sure it is true but i do not know how the answer should look like. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{nines}(n)$, the number $\underbrace{99 \ldots 9}_{n \text{ times}}$? And are you sure it's $10n$ (the $n$ isn't an exponent)?

Comment: oh I'm sorry, i edited it

Comment: Does this have to be in formal notation? Is it the notation or the actual induction you are struggling with?

Comment: A common formulation is that we want to prove $P(n)$ for all $n$, and by the induction principle it suffices to prove two "cases": the case $n=1$ is proved directly (the "starting case", for which one just argues that $P(1)$ must hold), while the case $n>1$ is proved as instance of $\forall k:P(k)\to P(k+1)$ with $k=n-1$, in other words $P(n)$ is now proved under the assumption of the hypothesis $P(n-1)$ (the "inductive case", where one "assumes that $P(n-1)$ is already established", which is just a manner of speaking to say that $P(n-1)$ may be assumed when proving $P(n)$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}9\cdot{10}^k$

We have $p(1) = \sum_{k=0}^09\cdot{10}^k=9\cdot10^0=9=10^1-1$

For the induction case, we assume our claim is true and attempt to show that assuming $p(k)$ implies $p(k+1)$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}9\cdot{10}^k=9\cdot10^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}9\cdot{10}^k$$
$$=9\cdot10^n+10^n-1=10^n(9+1)-1=10^{n+1}-1 \;\;\;\square$$